# open new window for fb login

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, logout

I want to login my user in my chatbox using fb. My chatbox is a shareable to other websites using javascript.

I want to do is, when a user click to a button "FB Login" it will open a window for fb login. then the user will accept the permissions, then.. it will be login to my chatbox.

My problem is, how the chatbox know if the user is logged in? a trigger event for this login? 
so that the chatbox is going to execute init(); for the change of the button
(change login Button --> logout button)..

My way is, first, user visit to a website(others website with my chatbox using javascript) --> chatbox run init()[a function that display the name of the chatbox, user name, and then the button login, if the user is logged in before the init() run, the button is logout]  --> if the user login, javascript will open a php file that redirect to the link of facebook login --> user permission accepted, the button will automatically changed from login to logout.. same as logging out. the button will change from logout to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript I know there are two ways to check if the current visitor is logged into Facebook and have accepted/not accepted your fb_app.

1. At page load using the [FB.init](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/)({status:true}) parameter and subscribing for [auth.statusChange](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) event.
2. After page load, even asynchronously, using [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginStatusUrl/)

In both cases, if there is no errors, a callback function will be fired. 
Here check if `response.status` exists, just to be sure there still are no errors, it should have three possible values:

1. `response.status == "connected"` - your visitor have accepted the Facebook app (and is logged into Facebook)
2. `response.status == "not_authorized"` - your visitor have NOT accepted the Facebook app (and is logged into Facebook)
3. `response.status == "unknow"` - Well, if everything works fine in your page, it actually means, your visitor is NOT logged into Facebook.

Subscribing `auth.statusChange` could be also useful if you want catch visitors that have logged into Facebook after first page view, during the visit, maybe even on a different tab in current browser.

In any case I suggest to use a Javascript debugger and do different tests: with connected, logged and not logged in users.

In the following line an update:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>test-facebook-login</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1234567890',               // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//www.yoursitehere.com/channel.html',
      status     : true,                       // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                        // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {

        if (window.console)
            window.console.log(response);

    });

    /*
    // On the other hand you could call this:

    FB.getLoginStatus( function(response) {

        if (window.console)
            window.console.log(response);

    });
    */


    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  (function(){
     if (document.getElementById('facebook-jssdk')) {return;}
     var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
     var facebookJS = document.createElement('script'); 
     facebookJS.id = 'facebook-jssdk';
     facebookJS.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     headElement.parentNode.appendChild(facebookJS);
   }());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the user visit the page and not logged in,the login link will display.  if he/she click login(after the page loads), it will log(response)? is it the use of FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {

        if (window.console)
            window.console.log(response);

    });

Comment: auth.statusChange is used right to be aware if the user is logged on Facebook or not, and even if is logged and has accepted your FB app